# Verify linearity of $T: \mathcal{P}_{n-m}(\text{F})\times\mathcal{P}_{m-1}(\text{F})\to\mathcal{P}_n(\text{F})$, $(q,r) \mapsto sq+r.$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know how to verify a linear map for $T$ that only takes one value, but I am not sure how to do for two arguments.
Here is the problem I am working out, from the book *Linear algebra done right*:

> Suppose that $p,s\in\mathcal{P}(\text{F})$, with $s\neq0$.  Then there exist unique polynomials $q,r\in\mathcal{P}(\text{F})$ such that $$p=sq+r$$ and $\deg r<\deg s$.
>
> *Proof.*  Let $n=\deg p$ and $m=\deg s$.  If $n<m$, then take $q=0$ and $r=p$ to get the desired result.  Thus, we can assume that $n\geq m$.
> Define $T:  \mathcal{P}_{n-m}(\text{F})\times\mathcal{P}_{m-1}(\text{F})\to\mathcal{P}_n(\text{F})$ by $$T(q,r)=sq+r.$$  The reader can easily verify that $T$ is a linear map.

Can you please show me how to verify that T is a linear map.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images cannot be searched and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you meed help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Also, are $\mathcal{P}(F)$ the polynomials over some field $F$, where subindices denote highest possible degree? If so please add this info to the question for sake of completeness.

Comment: @Viktor Glombik, yes the sub indices are the highest possible degree for each polynomial that can be used for the linear map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  You have to check that $T((q_1,r_1)+(q_2,r_2))=T(q_1,r_1)+T(q_2,r_2)$, and $T(k(q,r))=kT(q,r)$.

Comment: Can it be proved like: $T((q_1,r_1)+(q_2,r_2)) = T(q_1+q_2,r_1+r_2) = s(q_1+q_2)+ r_1 +r_2 = sq_1 + sq_2 +r_1 +r_2 = (sq_1 +r_1) +(sq_2 +r_2) = T(q_1,r_1) + T(q_2,r_2)$

Comment: Yes.  That would work.

Comment: Thank you for help :)